# .OleDbException Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: c#, sql, .net

My software generates a query to be inserted into my Access database, but the query that comes from my code, generates a `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException`, with an additional information:

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Debugging the code, the query generated works fine if I try to `insert` through Access software.

I really don't know why I'm getting this exception, my query is good!

Code:

```
OleDbConnection commodityDB = null;

try
{
    commodityDB = new OleDbConnection(connector);
    Console.WriteLine("Microsoft DB Connected!");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to create a database connection. \n{0}", ex.Message);
    return;
}

OleDbCommand cmder = new OleDbCommand(insert_txt,commodityDB);

string insert = string.Format("INSERT INTO Comm2 (Commodity_Name, Month_Code, Year_Com, ComCode, TradeDate,Open,High,Low,Close,Vol,OI) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}')", comName, comMonth, comYear, parts[0], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5], parts[6], parts[7], parts[8]);

commodityDB.Open();

cmder.CommandText = insert;
cmder.ExecuteNonQuery();
myAccessConn.Close();
```

An example of the query generated:

```
INSERT INTO Comm2 (Commodity_Name, Month_Code, Year_Com, ComCode, TradeDate, Open, High, Low, Close, Vol, OI) 
VALUES ('Australian Dollar', 'Y', '0', 'A6', '04/28/2014', '92740', '93157', '92435', '92568', '0', '0')
```

It works fine! Not on the software though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I'd opt for using OleDbParameters rather than string.Format to construct your query. That way you won't have to worry about strings containing quotes or anything else that is likely to make your SQL invalid. Have a look at the [Prepare method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.prepare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of OleDbCommand for an example on using parameters for an INSERT query like you are trying to achieve.

In your example though, I'm not sure what your `insert_txt` variable refers to, but given you seem to be overwriting that value, I'd exclude it from the constructor and only construct your `cmder` variable once you've got your `insert` variable set correctly. Try something like the following;

```
string insert = string.Format("INSERT INTO Comm2 (Commodity_Name, Month_Code, Year_Com, ComCode, TradeDate,Open,High,Low,Close,Vol,OI) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}')", comName, comMonth, comYear, parts[0], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5], parts[6], parts[7], parts[8]);

OleDbCommand cmder = new OleDbCommand(insert,commodityDB);


commodityDB.Open();

// cmder.CommandText = insert; // You probably won't need this anymore.
cmder.ExecuteNonQuery();
myAccessConn.Close();
```

Comment: That Worked! indeed It was my mistake to initialize the OleDbCommand with a diferrent variable. About the SQL Injection, I know about the risks, but this software will work locally in a secure place.

Comment: Excellent. It's not just about SQL injection though. What if, at some point down the track' you're reading a valid Commodity_Name that contains a quote character(ie Australian's Dollar: bad example, but just so you know that it is a genuine possibility without being a malicious attack) ? That'll break your string formatting and then SQL command. It's just a good habit to get into to use parameters and then you'll essentially do it because your used to it.